# No rule to make target 'excise1.o', needed by 'myprogram'. Stop

Tags: c

When I write a Makefile to compile,it appears.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

# 目标文件列表
OBJS = excise1.o

# 默认目标
all: myprogram

# 生成可执行文件
myprogram: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myprogram $(OBJS)

# 编译C文件为目标文件
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# 清理生成的文件
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) myprogram
```

how to compile my c program with Makefile

Comment: I recommend you learn about [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). If your source file is named `excise1.c` then all you really need is `myprogram: excise1.o`. That's it, no commands, no building, no other rule.

Comment: You might want to run make with the `-d` option to print lots of debugging information. The problem will be spotted quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

defines `x.o` for every `x.c` in the same folder.

while this line

```
OBJS = excise1.o
myprogram: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myprogram $(OBJS)
```

looks for `excise1.o` defined in the makefile, or in the same folder, which requires `excise1.c` in the same folder according to the first rule.

you need `excise1.c` in the same folder for this makefile to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your make can find the source file which usually named 'excise1.c', that means, you should have this file in the same folder where your Makefile exists. If it is already the case, you may need to check if the file dependencies in your source file has already been satisfied.